# What's a good amount of stable coin to deposit into a liquidity pool?

Tags: solidity, tokens

What's a good amount of stable coin to deposit into the liquidity pool and what percentage of the token's supply should be in a liquidity pool?

Answer (score 2):

Well it's an interesting question that's hard to answer without more explanations, so I would say:

7

Comment: I'd go with 9, but really depends on what  your expectations are.